# xcodebuild intermittently fails with message about run destination not being valid

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm trying to setup some automation for building my app and am having some non-deterministic behavior from xcodebuild on the command line. I'm using Xcode 5 currently and am trying to run a command like the following:

```
xcodebuild -target <MY-TARGET> -scheme <MY-SCHEME> -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES clean build test CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='/custom/build/dir'
```

About 50% of the time when I run this command, the build fails immediately and gives me the following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project <MY-PROJECT> with scheme <MY-SCHEME>.
Reason: The run destination iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme '<MY-SCHEME>'.
```

Other times, the command runs just fine. Has anyone else run in to this issue with XCode 5 or earlier. I've tried things I read elsewhere like clearing out the build products dori (the CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR) and DerivedData before each run and also explicitly specifying iphonesimulator7.0 for the sdk. None of these approaches worked for me, however.

Comment: Please file a bug report with Apple: http://bugreport.apple.com